# Do I need to have Airpcap?

Tags: wireless, sniffer, wireshark

I am learning system security in an online course. In a practical experiment I tried to monitor the traffic through my router using wireshark1.10.3. But I have a feeling that it only sensing traffic from my windows laptop to the router, but not all systems connected to the router.

Do I need to have a Airpcap adapter to monitor all the packets from my router or is there any alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking to monitor packets between your computer as a client on the network and the router and other wireless clients and the router? If you're using windows, it looks like the answer is yes: you'll need to purchase Airpcap.

http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/8504/supported-adapters-for-wireless-packet-capturing

If you're attempting to monitor at some other point, you might clarify?  Are you capturing on the router?  On the WAN port of the router?  Or are you collecting as a client on the network and expecting to see activity of wired clients in your capture?

Comment: I want to collect it as client on the network and monitor the activity of the other wireless clients connected to that router.Though I feel its little odd to capture or monitor the packets with out having a adapter that can tune in I want to know if the existing hardware in my laptop can do the job. And you said that if I am using windows 'Yes' if I use Backtrack or kali linux in VMware player can I monitor withot using Airpcap?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to monitor the other wireless clients, you don't need a particular adapter as any adapter can sniff the wireless signals over the air. However, if you want to inject specially crafted packets (such as WEP cracking), you need to have an adapter that can support injection. If you want to test your wireless adapter if it supports injection or not, you can use the aireplay-ng which is part of the aircrack-ng suite of tools. The command to test a basic injection is:

```
aireplay-ng -9 wlan0
```

Microsoft Windows has only a single Adapter that supports raw packet injection which is the Airpcap adapter. If you plan to use a Linux distribution such as BackTrack or Kali, any modern wireless adapter is capable of injecting raw packets. 
You can find further details about the injection test procedure at [aircrack-ng injection test page](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=injection_test).
You cannot use VMWare or any other virtualized environment since it will mount the wireless adapter as Ethernet device which can't sniff or inject into the wireless network.

Comment: FYI - you can use VMWare with a Linux test, but you have to use a USB WiFi adapter (unless there's a wifi adapter that now supports ESXi PCI passthrough, of course).  Please investigate the legal aspects of active attacks (aireplay-ng, etc.) like injection and if you choose to use such an active attack be absolutely certain to limit the target to your own device(s).

Comment: Thank you. Yes the VMware won't mount the internal WiFi adapter but any external adapter can be used without any problem. Wireless USB adapter from Alpha networks is a popular one but practically any modern WiFi adapter is capable of doing injection.

Answer (score 1):

> Do i need to have a Airpcap adapter to monitor all the packets from my router or is there any alternative?

For Wireshark, or any other application that uses WinPcap to capture traffic, you need an AirPcap adapter.

For [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865), you won't need (and can't use) an AirPcap adapter; however, you will need Windows Vista or later, and an adapter that supports "Native Wi-Fi" (I don't know how to determine whether your laptop's adapter does other than downloading Network Monitor and installing it and trying it).  Some vendors of competing network analyzers that provide their own drivers for Wi-Fi adapters say that "Native Wi-Fi", for capturing in "monitor mode", doesn't work very well for some adapters.